# bounded but not convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am not sure that if this question has a positive answer...I am looking for a sequence of real numbers $(p_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ such that
$-1<\lim _{n}\inf p_{n}\leq \lim_{n}\sup p_{n} <1$ (as usual, "lim inf" and "lim sup" de denote here the infimin and supremum limits), but that do not exist $0<P<1$ such that $|p_{n}|\leq P$ for each $n$.

What do yo think?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such sequence.

**Hint:** Assume otherwise, that $\left\{P_n\right\}$ is a sequence as described. Consider $P_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$, and prove that there is a subsequence of $\left\{p_n\right\}$ which converges to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, it seem that your sequence work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $(p_n)=\{-9,9,0,0,0,0,0,\dots\}$.

Certainly $\liminf p_n=\limsup p_n=0$, so $-1<\liminf p_n=\limsup p_n<1$.

However there is no $0<P<1$ such that $|9|\leq P$.

This seems like cheating though. Do you mean to have $0<P$?